# Eclipse : Inlay Hints request failed. No resource provided

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I use a clean installation of Eclipse PHP 2022-12 on Windows 10. I added the Wild Web Development extension to provide support for HTML, CSS and JavaScript development. The code assistant works for HTML and CSS but not for JavaScript. I get this error:

```
LSP (JavaScript-TypeScript Language Server)
Inlay Hints request failed. No resource provided
```

My need is very basic; writing simple code with JavaScript. I don't need to use TypeScript or Node.js.

Comment: What you have configured in the preferences _JS/TS (Wild Web Developer) > JavaScript > Inlay Hint_? Does it work with a new workspace (_File > Switch Workspace > Other..._)? Wild Web Developer uses the JavaScript-TypeScript language server taken from VS Code that Node.js to be run and which communicates via the [Language Server Protocol (LSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) with other parts of the Wild Web Developer Eclipse plugin written in Java.

Comment: I checked all the options in  JS/TS (Wild Web Developer) > JavaScript > Inlay Hint. What I understood is that I have to install a server Node.js and run it for having code completion?

Comment: No, there is an embedded Node.js in the Wild Web Developer plugin.

Comment: @howlger IFF they also install that Feature. It's separated.

Comment: I see the embedded Node.js extension was also installed but the code assistant is still not working.

Comment: @nitind [It is included, but with `optional="true"`](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/blob/e0a067559f791f445b7d7a32877ba62ea08a7aaf/org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.feature/feature.xml#L22-L25).

Comment: @user Please tell what you have configured in the preferences _JS/TS (Wild Web Developer) > JavaScript > Inlay Hint_? Does it work with a fresh workspace or not? For me, everything works fine. So please improve your question by adding the information I asked for. Please also tell the version of Wild Web Developer you installed.

Comment: I confirm it works when I start with a clean workspace. I imported successfully my PHP project and the code assistant works for JS but not for my JQuery library witch is included within the project. The version of WWD is 1.0.1